# Importing the same object from the same module, in two different modules:

Tags: python, object, module, namespaces

module1.py:

```
from somemod import something
import module2
```

module2.py:

```
from somemod import something
```

Is `something` in `module1` the exact same object as `something` in `module2`?

For example, if before importing module2, module1 would do `something.val = 10`. Could module2 get the value by doing `something.val`? Or does it get a different object?

Asked differently: **does `import` execute an imported module even if it was already imported in the interpreter session, in a different module?**

Also, is it necessary to `from somemod import something` in module2 if module1 already imported it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's the same object. Modules, like everything else in Python, are objects that exist in memory and referenced by a name. The `import` statement does two things: one, if the requested module does not yet exist, executes the code in the imported file and two, makes it available as a module. Subsequent import statements will skip the first step. This means that in `module1`, the names `module1.something` and `module1.module2.something` both refer to the same object created the first time `somemod` was imported.

Comment: So in a python interpreter session, a module may only be executed once ever?

Comment: That is correct. It's much simpler to be able to assume that the code in a module will be executed exactly once, no matter how many times it is imported from various other modules.

Comment: I was thinking of a problem more like this. If I import the same module that I installed with pip, from two different classes, it does not eat up more memory than importing it just once right?