# Access objects in namespace of parent package to imported subpackage?

Tags: python-import

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30483269/2153235) is an excellent
description how namespaces are affected by imports.  I found, however,
that the following point is only partially true:

- `import packagename.nestedmodule` sets `packagename = sys.modules['packagename']` (no matter how many addional levels you
  add)

I performed the following from the Spyder console:

```
import pyspark.sql as sql, sys
```

Here, `pyspark` is a package while `sql` is a subpackage (both of
which are also modules).

The above did *not* create a `pyspark` object in the namespace of the
REPL.  It did, however, create entry `sys.modules["pyspark"]` in
addition to `sys.modules["pyspark.sql"]`.

**Is there any way to access the namespace for parent package,
corresonding to `sys.modules["pyspark"]` without having to import
it separately?**  Though I'm not 100% certain, the entry
`sys.modules["pyspark"]` suggests to me that the code in
`pyspark/__init__.py` was already executed.  If so, then the objects
are already floating around in some scope somewhere, maintained by
Python.

This question differs from my [past
question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77055375), but the
answer here could inform the answer to the older question.

**Afternote:** *mr_mo* provides an explanation of the mechanisms to accomplish this, but for anyone looking for a quick code example, you would bring the (say) `pyspark` namespace into the current namespace using `pyspark=sys.modules["pyspark"]`.  You can confirm accessibility to the objects therein by `dir(pyspark)`.

Comment: Since I've seen pro engineers struggle with this subject, allow me to give a proper educative answer. Meanwhile (will take a few minutes at least), I can refer you to https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#regular-packages and https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html , "the implementation of import".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access modules and their objects, you'll need to either import them to your namespace or use `sys.modules`. **It is a dictionary that maps module name to the module**. Depending on what you trying to achieve (details would help), that can also be done dynamically by the import statement or directly by the "implementation of the import statement", which is [importlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html). See [importlib.import_module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module), and note that a module can be an object in your namespace. So through that, you can do for example

```
# Case 1
catalog = importlib.import_module('catalog','pyspark.sql').
Database = catalog.Database
```

which is equivalent to

```
# Case 2
from pyspark.sql import catalog
Database = catalog.Database
```

but not to

```
# Case 3
from pyspark.sql.catalog import Database
```

The differences between the 3 cases is your `locals()` in your namespace. While [`pyspark.__init__.py`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/__init__.py) and `pyspark.sql.__init__.py`, both are executed, the resulting objects aren't bound to names in the current namspace; only the one specified by the import statement is. Case #1 and #2 are equivalent, maybe except the fact that you'll need to import importlib first (ironic).

**The key-takeaway** is that [`sys.modules`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.modules) is the underlying mechanism use in the import system, that stores a mapping (dict) of module name to module object. It can be used as a replacement to import statement for loaded modules, but **import statement achieves the same goal**. As explained in [PEP451](https://peps.python.org/pep-0451/), import system use this object in the underlying implementation to reuse loaded modules, instead of reloading. This saves time, but also create a singleton pattern on modules, making those unique for all imports under the same package name.

Comment: Thanks, mr_mo.  I did look at the import implementation webpage, but being new to Python and Spark, it is too big a step for me right now.  But based on the bolded text in your answer, I was able to issue `pyspark=sys.modules["pyspark"]; dir(pyspark)` and access the parent package namespace. The word *import* might be too ambiguous to discern the nuances in your answer. Would it be clearer to say that the `__init__.py` files are executed but the resulting objects aren't bound to names in the current namespace, and that they are maintained in namespaces that are accessible via `sys.modules`?

Comment: My understanding is that yes, every package is imported also as a module (perhaps it depends on some details here), and discoverable by sys.modules. This is the under-the-hood for the import statement: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.11/Lib/importlib/_bootstrap.py#L1182

Comment: Thanks, mr_mo.  As I mentioned, in the 2nd last paragraph of your answer, the term "import" might be too-overloaded to be unambiguous.  I've revised your answer in accordance with my comment above to hopefully remove this ambiguity. Of course, I am a newbie, so if revision is mistaken, thanks if you can help dispel my misconception.

Comment: In your answer, you asked what I was trying to achieve. I don't avoid duplicating objects by importing [sub]packages if they already reside in an active namespace. I would rather access the namespace in which they reside, e.g., using `sys.modules`, as you suggested. This avoids (say) me creating a `pyspark.sql` namespace and an `sql` namespace that replicates all the objects. Of course, this assumes that the objects are replicated. For all I know, Python recognizes that them as identical and simply has both keys in `sys.modules`, but the corresponding values reference the same namespace.

Comment: @user2153235 Thanks for the edit. Python import the same modules, assuming under the same package name, as singletons. This was introduced in https://peps.python.org/pep-0451/ to avoid multiple loading of modules, which executes the module code under the specific namespace. This is why you check `__name__ == "__main__"` to create clauses that entered only when executed as scripts. The short answer is - using the import statement multiple times doesn't really "load" the module several times. It access the module via `sys.modules` for you. See the cpython implementation I attached last comment.

Comment: I'm just learning Python right now, so I am not well positioned to delve into the implementation source code to infer the designed-for behaviour (though I did take a look). I also looked at the PEP 451 that you cited, and least found the heading "How Reloading Will Work". Again, being a newbie, it's hard to make sense of it. I can't find the relevant passage that makes it clear what happens when a module appears twice in `sys.modules` under two or more different keys.

Comment: You mentioned singleton loading, but my understanding of singletons is in the context of multidimensional arrays, so it's not clear to me that a module's entire set of objects are not replicated. You also commented that instead of loading modules more than once, the module is simply accesses the 1st set of module objects via `sys.modules`. But the *keys* in `sys.modules` would differ, e.g., `pyspark.sql` versus `sql`. As I suggested above, would this mean that *values* for both `sys.modules` entries contain a reference to the same set of module objects?

Comment: It looks like the answer to whether modules are replicated is "no"
(see
[here](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-bad-practice-to-import-the-same-module-in-multiple-files)
and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32910454)). I was
misconceived about the possibility that the same module can appear
under multiples keys in the `sys.modules` dictionary. As far as I can
see, a module's key will always be a dot-path to the module's `*.py`
file or the package's folder, with the root being one of the paths in
`sys.path`.  If I'm wrong about this, I welcome being educated about
it.

Comment: The short answer is you are correct. Modules are loaded only once, hence can be used as singletons. Removing the key from `sys.modules` actually is a hack for reloading. 

Having said that, I see no point in accessing via `sys.modules` and not just importing. The syntax do the same with few extra lines, this is O(1) in terms of time.

Sorry for not being able to provide more information earlier, would love to edit in the future and explain how it actually works. It is heavy stuff for beginners and even casual engineers (many software engineers are casual python programmers).

Comment: Thanks.  I think this clears it up.  I also looked up "singleton".  It's use in multidimensional arrays is a Matlab convention.  More generally, it is a design pattern ensuring no replication of an object of a certain class.  It doesn't *exactly* match your meaning of not replicating a specific module, but I get the idea.

Comment: Singleton is mathematical definition (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_(mathematics)) of a on-point set. Modules in python, after PEP451, became singletons. If you'd look up how to create a singleton in python, you'll probable meet https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760685/creating-a-singleton-in-python in one of the first results. Method 5 is also valid. It has it's downsides, but simpler than other approaches. Good luck on your project!

Comment: The mathematical definition of singleton is more like Matlab's, as one of the many dimensions has only one possible value.  The singleton design pattern, which is the topic of your 2nd link, is beyond my OOP chops (I am not a developer).  I know that anyone who spends the time will eventually figure it out, but it's more a matter of the other things are one is more expected to confront.  I appreciate the references, however!